# jquery waypoints issue when webpage is zoomed

Tags: jquery, css

I have a webpage made of vertical slides, each one is a class "page" in css:

```
<body>

<div class="page">
 .....
</div>

<div class="page">
 .....
</div>

</body>
```

and each page is 100% height, so it takes all the screen.
I use waypoints to color the menu entry that corresponds to the current slide, I use it succesfully with directions up&down, but there is an issue: if I load the page and the I zoom it (for example at 150%), waypoints offsets don't work correctly because they are configured on the page at 100%, so the menu entry that is coloured when I scroll down is not the correct one. Can you help me?